# How to access StatefulSet with other PODs

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I have a running Elasticsearch STS with a headless Service assigned to it:

svc.yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: elasticsearch-namespace
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      name: rest
    - port: 9300
      name: inter-node
```

stateful.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: elasticsearch-namespace
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
          - name: elasticsearch-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: elasticsearch-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-persistent-storage
        labels:
          app: elasticsearch
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        storageClassName: elasticsearch-storageclass
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 20Gi
```

The question is: how to access this STS with PODs of Deployment Kind? Let's say, using this Redis POD:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-ws-app
  labels:
    app: redis-ws-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-ws-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-ws-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis-ws-app
        image: redis:latest
        command: [ "redis-server"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

I have been trying to create another service, that would enable me to access it from the outside, but without any luck:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-tcp
  namespace: elasticsearch-namespace
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9200
    targetPort: 9200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would reach it directly hitting the headless service. As an example, this `StatefulSet` and this `Service`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-headless
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
```

I could reach the pods of the statefulset, through the headless service from any pod within the cluster:

```
/ # curl -I nginx-headless
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.0
Date: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 12:36:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 May 2020 15:00:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5ecd2f04-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The singularity of the headless service, is that it doesn't create `iptable` rules for that service. So, when you query that service,  it goes to kube-dns (or CoreDNS), and it returns the backends, rather then the IP address is the service itself. So, if you do `nslookup`, for example, it will return all the backends (pods) of that service:

```
/ # nslookup nginx-headless

Name:      nginx-headless
Address 1: 10.56.1.44
Address 2: 10.56.1.45
Address 3: 10.56.1.46
Address 4: 10.56.1.47
```

And it won't have any `iptable` rules assigned to it:

```
$ sudo iptables-save | grep -i nginx-headless
$
```

Unlike a normal service, that would return the IP address of the service itself:

```
/ # nslookup nginx

Name:      nginx
Address 1: 10.60.15.30 nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
```

And it will have `iptable` rules assigned to it:

```
$ sudo iptables-save | grep -i nginx
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.56.0.0/14 -d 10.60.15.30/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nginx: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.60.15.30/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nginx: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-4N57TFCL4MD7ZTDA
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you have written you could reach pods of the statefulset using any pod within the cluster. It means, that you could connect using any nginx pod, am I right? The case is that I need to conncet with the cluster using pods that are not a part of it

Comment: Just in case you still have the doubt, you can't reach a headless service from outside the cluster. You would need to find out a way to get into it, then hit the service. But that seems cumbersome. Why do you need it to be headless?

Answer (score 0):

User @suren was right about the headless service. In my case, I was just using a wrong reference.

```
The Kube-DNS naming convention is 
service.namespace.svc.cluster-domain.tld 
and the default cluster domain is cluster.local
```

In my case, the in order to reach the pod, one has to use:

```
curl -I elasticsearch.elasticsearch-namespace
```